# ¿Cómo funciona el operador "\<" en el comando test de Bash?

Tags: bash, condiciones, operador

Hace unos días un compañero de la universidad me comentó que en la clase de Programación para Sistemas donde enseñan los comienzos de programación en Bash y en lenguaje C, le propusieron la siguiente pregunta:

```
$ echo $SHELL
/bin/bash
$ [ 10 \< 5 ]
$ echo $?
0
```

¿Por qué es cierta la condicion? Y la verdad es que no supe responderle porque no sé que es el operador `\<` y he buscado por la documentación del comando `test` y por Google y no encuentro nada.

¿Alguien sabría responderle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Esta condición es cierta porque `\<` sirve para comparar cadenas. Por ello, al comparar `10` con `5` se fija primero en el primer carácter de cada cadena y encuentra `1` y `5`, por lo que determina que `10` es menor que `5`.

Veamos el uso estándar de este operador:

```
$ [ a \< b ] && echo "a es menor" || echo "b es menor"
a es menor
$ [ c \< b ] && echo "c es menor" || echo "b es menor"
b es menor
```

Si se comparan números, los evalua de acuerdo con su posición en la tabla de caracteres. Así, al comparar `10` con `2` se fijará primero en el `1` y el `2` y determinará que `10` es menor que `2`:

```
$ [ 1 \< 2 ] && echo "1 es menor" || echo "2 es menor"
1 es menor
$ [ 3 \< 2 ] && echo "3 es menor" || echo "2 es menor"
2 es menor
```

Pero:

```
$ [ 10 \< 2 ] && echo "10 es menor" || echo "2 es menor"
10 es menor
```

Esto explica que `[ 10 \< 5 ]` se evalúe como cierto:

```
$ [ 10 \< 5 ]
$ echo $?
0
```

Que, como mostré en otros ejemplos, podemos validar de una forma más gráfica con un operador ternario `[ ] && si cierto || si falso`:

```
$ [ 10 \< 5 ] && echo "10 es menor" || echo "5 es menor"
10 es menor
```

---

Si lo que quieres es realizar comparaciones de números, utiliza:

| operador | significado |
| --- | --- |
| -eq | igual |
| -lt | menor estricto |
| -le | menor o igual |
| -gt | mayor estricto |
| -ge | menor o igual |

Por ejemplo:

```
$ [ 10 -lt 2 ] && echo "10 es menor" || echo "2 es menor"
2 es menor
```

Nótese que `\<` efectúa comparaciones de cadenas en Bash, Korn Shell, zsh. No está especificado en POSIX, por lo que shell seguramente no lo tenga. ([Referencia](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6073461/1983854)).